# How can multiple threads read a static data(arraylist)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an arraylist with 10000 records. Current only one thread is accessing this arraylist .This single thread  reads data from this arraylist In a batch if 100 elements ,then makes a rest call with with this 100 elements. It executes in a for loop for 10000/100 = 100 times. It takes 15 min to complete the 100 times.

I did it in Single thread .How to make the rest call async or How to do it in multiple threads.

Any example please.

Comment: You need to provide more detail  How do you know the problem is related to concurrent processing?  Please provide  a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Java example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create your ArrayList with 10000 records
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();

        // Create an ExecutorService with multiple threads
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        // Create a list to store the CompletableFuture objects
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        // Split the records into batches of 100
        int batchSize = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i += batchSize) {
            final int startIndex = i;
            final int endIndex = Math.min(i + batchSize, records.size());

            // Create a CompletableFuture for each batch
            CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                // Process the batch and make the REST call
                processBatch(records.subList(startIndex, endIndex));
            }, executorService);

            // Add the CompletableFuture to the list
            futures.add(future);
        }

        // Wait for all the CompletableFuture objects to complete
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        try {
            allFutures.get(); // Wait for completion
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Shut down the ExecutorService
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private static void processBatch(List<String> batch) {
        // Make the REST call using the batch of elements
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it was generated using ChapGPT. Using AI technology to generate answers is forbidden on this site.  Additionally, there was no detailed explanation of what you were doing, and why (what API lasses you used, how they work, etc).